# Error in MySQL Query in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm receiving an unexpected error on my MySQL query, can anyone help me discover why?

Error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON users.id =
>   user_auth_tickets.user_id WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = 'N' at
>   line 1

Query:

```
dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
  "FROM users" +
  "JOIN user_auth_tickets " +
  "ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id " +
  "WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = @sso AND last_ip = @lastIp " +
  "LIMIT 1"
);
```

Comment: You are running a `SELECT` then a join right after with no `;` to say that they are separate statements. Im pretty sure this is what's triggering your error

Comment: @helloworld - Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You have two `WHERE` clauses in your query.
It just appears you may have had a shorter initial query, where you did place the `WHERE` clause properly, but then later decided to `JOIN` additional tables and assumed additional conditions. At that time you would have needed to restructure the query, as per the syntax hierarchy in the reference below, the `WHERE` comes **after** your table references.

[image: OPs Question]

[Per the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual - SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

> The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that
>   rows must satisfy to be selected. where_condition is an expression
>   that evaluates to true for each row to be selected. The statement
>   selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.

Remove the first `WHERE`, and append the `last_ip = @lastIp` to the lower `WHERE`.

For example:

```
dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
"FROM users " +
"JOIN user_auth_ticket ON users.id = user_auth_ticket.user_id " +
"WHERE user_auth_ticket.auth_ticket = @sso AND last_ip = @lastIp " +
"LIMIT 1"
);
```

Comment: You missed the space after `@lastIp` but this worked, thank you.

Comment: @helloworld I have updated my answer, if it is what you need to solve this question, please mark as 'accepted' thank you!!

Comment: I'm not getting 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = 'N' at line 1'

Comment: @helloworld I have updated my answer with more information and correction to spacing on the concatenated string. Can I help you more?